# The image of $T_2$

Tags: general-topology

Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a bijection (which may or may not be continuous). What property P on $X$ guarantees that $Y$ is Hausdorff? It is clear that if $X$ is $T_2$ and $f$ is open , then $Y$ is $T_2$. What else?

Comment: I think we also need to impose conditions on $f$ as in your example, right? Otherwise, we can always take $Y = X$ equipped with the trivial topology.

Comment: As stated the problem is too broad.

Comment: X is single point space.